# How to do change the string format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how to change the string format.
`2,4,6,9`
to 
`[2],[4],[6],[9]`

```
  int[] terms = termsList.ToArray();
  var result = string.Join(",", terms);
```

In result i get a `2,4,6,9`but i want to get `[2],[4],[6],[9]` format

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this

```
string result = String.Join(",", terms.ToList().ConvertAll(i => "["+i.ToString()+"]"));
```

elegant approach would be

```
string result = String.Join(",", terms.Select(x => "[" + x + "]"));
```

I liked this,

```
string result = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(terms, s => $"[{s}]"));
```

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L2fElD)

Comment: `.toArray()` is superfluous

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ and string interpolation:

```
var terms = new []{ 2, 4, 6, 9 };
var str = string.Join(",", terms.Select(x => $"[{x}]"));
```

Result

> [2],[4],[6],[9]